# Error Message in Eclipse with Blackberry Plugin: Signature tool was not found

Tags: blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I'm using Eclipse Galileo R2 (32bit) on a Windows 7 machine with the Blackberry Eclipse Plugin v1.1.2. The plugin installation completed without any errors. In the "Problems" tab, I get an error, and I am unable to build my project.

This error reads: Signature tool was not found.

I have set the permissions on my Eclipse folder to Everyone: Full Control

I have verified that the signature tool (SignatureTool.jar) exists: C:\Program Files (x86)\Eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack5.0.0_5.0.0.25\components\bin

Am I missing something here?

Why can't the plugin see the the signature tool?

Answer (score 0):

Did you installed the keys provided by RIM. If not then you need to buy certificate which costs 20$ and then install in the eclipse.

The name of three certificates will be something like this client-RRT-2492457023.csi. Once successful installation is over you need to check inside

C:\Program Files (x86)\Eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack5.0.0_5.0.0.25\components\bin

search for the sigtool.csk, sigtool.db and sigtool.set. Once these three files found then your installation is successful.